# I need to make regex pattern which can allow any case extensions like jpg JPG without hardcoding and it can work on React

Tags: regex

Currently, I am working on this
regex `^(?=[a-zA-Z\S\s]{1,252}$)[\S\s ]*\.(jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|docx|doc|txt|xls|xlsx)$` but it only takes `filename.extension` in lower case (`abc.jpg`), but if I enter like `abc.JPG` or `abc.Jpg` it is not matching.

Also, I tried putting `/i`, at the end, but it was not working.

Even this regex `^(?U)(?=[\S\s]{1,252}$)[\S\s ]*\.((?i)jpeg|jpg|png|pdf|docx|doc|txt|xls|xlsx)` - was also not working. Tried many things but was not working.

plz help me in finding out a regex but changing my current regex `^(?=[a-zA-Z\S\s]{1,252}$)[\S\s ]*\.(jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|docx|doc|txt|xls|xlsx)$` so that it can take different case extensions too without hardcoding so that it will match filenames like `abc.jpg`, `abc.Jpg`, `abc.JPG`

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you use lookahead (maybe it's about something not mentioned in the question), but `^.+\.(?i)(jpeg|jpg|pdf|png|docx|doc|txt|xls|xlsx)$` should validate filenames like you described.

Check example [here](https://regex101.com/r/mqcV4S/1)

Comment: but it is not working already i mentioned i don't know why but in while building its saying that regex format is not matched

Comment: As you can see in provided link this regex matches what is needed, not matches what is not needed. @prabhat, edit the question and provide code for how you are using this regex.